Cómo obtener los registros de hace 2 días
Tengo que crear un crontab, para que envié un aviso al usuario vía email, (la parte de la configuración del correo la tengo clara), el asunto es que la consulta MySQL, no me funciona, o no lo estoy haciendo bien, es por ello que solicito ayuda para comprender mejor dónde tengo la falla, por favor.
Ahora explico mi consulta.
Tengo 2 tablas, documentos y clientes.
Tabla documentos:



Field
Type




id_documento
int(11)


fecha
date


numero
varchar(12)


tipo
varchar(50)


estado
tinyint(1) 1


cliente_id
int(11)



Tabla clientes:



Field
Type




id_cliente
int(11)


nombre
varchar(50)


rut
varchar(12)


email
varchar(255)


telefono
varchar(36)


direccion
varchar(255)


estado
tinyint(1)



Mi consulta SQL:
SELECT d.id_documento, d.fecha, d.numero, d.tipo, d.estado, d.cliente_id, c.id_cliente, c.nombre, c.rut, c.email, c.estado
FROM documentos d
INNER JOIN clientes c
ON d.cliente_id = c.id_cliente
WHERE d.fecha = DATE_ADD(d.fecha, INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
  AND d.estado=1 
  AND d.tipo='Bono'

Esta consulta no da error, pero no muestra ningún dato.
La idea es que envié un correo al cliente después de 2 días desde la fecha del documento, para recordar que aún no se ha recibido el bono.
Espero haber explicado bien la situación.

En la consulta estás comparando la fecha que tenga el registro, con la fecha del registro + 2 días... Eso será siempre falso. Entiendo que lo que quieres ver es que la fecha actual sea igual o mayor a la fecha del campo + 2 días...

Lo que necesito es que envié un correo después de 2 días de la fecha del registro.

"que envié un correo al cliente después de 2 días desde la fecha del documento, para recordar que aún no se ha recibido el bono" y si ya lo recibieron que pasa?? Cada cuanto se va a ejecutar el Cronjob?? Porque si el CJ se va a ejecutar todos los días, desde el momento, al crear el registro puedes sumarle 2 días y guardarlo en otro campo, luego con el CJ puedes recorrer todos los clientes que debas enviarle el email hoy, por ejemplo. Eso si es que tu DB no escalará enormemente con el tiempo. Además jakala ya te dio una idea de como hacerlo también.

Como bien señala @OCHOA esto no debería depender solamente de campos basados en fecha. Imagina que hay algún problema en un momento dado y los mensajes no se mandan ese día. Cuando el cron se ejecute al día siguiente, esos registros de cuando hubo problema no entrarán en la verificación y los mensajes quedarán sin enviarse a esos registros. Tú puedes tener una tabla de control donde guardes id_documento e irla llenando desde la lógica del archivo que dispara el cron, verificando los documentos que aún no existen en esa tabla de control pero que sí existen en la tabla documentos.

Cuando se reciba el bono, el admin del sistema, cambiará el estado, en este momento es 1=Pendiente y debe cambiar a 0=Recibido

La verdad que el CJ se enviará cada 2 días, dependiendo si es Estado es 1 o Cero, osea día 2, día 4, y día 6

dia 2, o sea 2 dias despues de la fecha del documento.. o sea.. que d.fecha no puede ser igual a nada... pero si, la fecha de hoy puede ser igual a d.fecha +2 o +4 o +6 o lo que sea.. no?

@gbianchi  No entendí bien pero creo que algo así debe ser, lo que me interesa es que la consulta MySQL, devuelva los datos solicitados, con la fecha +2 días, lo del CJ, creo tenerlo claro como funciona, mi problema es la consulta SQL.

Y entonces es lo que te dijeron en todos los comentarios.. es la fecha de registro = a la fecha de hoy mas 2.. mas 4.. etc... ... o que tipo de fechas manejas ahi???

He respondido a la pregunta principal, que es sobre SQL. Creo que habría que quitar el ruido adicional, sobre para qué quieres los datos. Las consideraciones que han hecho en comentarios pueden ser válidas, o no, pero no tienen que ver con la pregunta, de acuerdo a las etiquetas, y se dan por el contexto que es explicado en el texto.

Lo que buscas es obtener los registros de hace dos días.
Para obtener dichos registros, necesitas primero obtener la fecha de hoy, que lo haces con la función curdate() y luego restarle dos días, que lo haces con la función adddate()
Esta consulta te devuelve la fecha de hace dos días:
select adddate(curdate(), -2)

fiddle
Ojo, que el negativo en el parámetro es para obtener la fecha de hace dos días y no la fecha de 2 días en el futuro.
Adaptando tu consulta, la condición de fecha sería:
WHERE d.fecha = adddate(curdate(), -2) 


Gracias @jachguate
WHERE d.fecha = adddate(curdate(), -2) esto funcionó, ahora se pueden poner en la misma consulta -4 -6 por ejemplo,
AND d.fecha = adddate(curdate(), -4)
AND d.fecha = adddate(curdate(), -6)? o hay que hacer archivos diferentes para el Cron?

Si pones otra condición de fecha con and, no te va a devolver ningún registro, pues no va a haber alguno que cumla con ambas condiciones a la vez (que eso significa el and. Para obtener los que son de una fecha u otra, puedes preparar una sentencia con varias condiciones de igualdad de fecha con el operador or, o una única condición con el operador in.
